# Loading multiple parquet files into R from URL (Dropbox folder)

Tags: r, url, parquet

I'm trying to load multiple parquet files from my Dropbox folder's URL (I did not set those files to local just to save my computer memory). I used the following code, but it returns nothing.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files(path = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g8ck3t859uahkdi/AADw-kp7EYfU-SMZc4mmtCM2a?dl=1", pattern = "*.parquet", full.names = T)

tbl <- sapply(files, read_parquet, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

I've referenced [this](https://blog.exploratory.io/how-to-read-multiple-excel-or-csv-files-together-42af5d314a10) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246739/download-multiple-files-using-download-file-function), but couldn't figure out how to.

I used windows machine for this task (do I need to set `mode` to `"wb"`?) but may switch to Mac if need be.

Comment: can you check the `length(files)`

Comment: IIn the link, it is reading the files from a directory.  But in your code, it is directing to an url

Comment: R returns `length(files)` = 0, but I store 5 files in that folder.

Comment: Or should I set `AADw-kp7EYfU-SMZc4mmtCM2a?dl=` 0 ?

Comment: Can you try the solution posted below.  It works for me

Comment: @akrun It should work, because the total rows for the 5 files in that folder is exactly what you got, but when I pasted and executed your code on my machine, the last line of code shows 0. I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: Have you changed the path i.e. `/path/to/yourfolder/filenew.zip`  You may change it to your Downloads folder or so

Comment: I tested this on a mac

Comment: For the `filezip`, do I need to supply a new folder path?

Comment: i did exactly as in the solution

Comment: I kept getting 0 from the last line of code. I think the `/path/to/yourfolder/` is the one I don't know how to deal with, should I replace it with a temporary folder followed by `filenew.zip` or `filenew`?

Comment: What is your `getwd()`.  Then if you want to create those folders in the working directoryt. just do `filezip <- "filenew.zip"` and `new_folder <- "filenew"`

Comment: I got a warning message `Warning message:
In unzip(filezip, exdir = new_folder) :
  error -1 in extracting from zip file' and still got `nrow(tbl)` = 0

Comment: As I said, I did this in `mac`

Comment: Is it working on mac

Comment: I tried this on a Mac, it finally works (only need to remove `wb`). Just wondering if your code could work on PC? But your answer is still highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is some issue on windows for reading/writing parquet as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815817/issue-with-writing-parquet-files-via-arrow-package-in-r)

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I should switch this task on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the second option of downloading to a destination folder, then

```
library(arrow)
library(purrr)
url <- "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g8ck3t859uahkdi/AADw-kp7EYfU-SMZc4mmtCM2a?dl=1"
filezip <- "/path/to/yourfolder/filenew.zip"
new_folder <-  "/path/to/yourfolder/filenew"
download.file(url, filezip, mode = "wb")
unzip(filezip, exdir = new_folder)
files <- list.files(path = new_folder, 
            pattern = "\\.parquet$", full.names = TRUE)
tbl <- map_dfr(files, read_parquet) 
nrow(tbl)
#[1] 168019
```